# Angular momentum conservation in a rocket-sun-moon system

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Let us describe a rocket traveling from earth to the moon and back. I want to show that the rocket's angular momentum is conserved to be able to conclude that the rocket's motion is restricted to a two-dimensional plane. Let us assume that the earth is in the origin and the moon is located at $\boldsymbol{r}_\mathrm{M} = d\boldsymbol{e}_1$, where $d$ is the distance between earth and moon.

Let $\Phi(\boldsymbol{r}) = -\gamma\left(\frac{m_\mathrm{E}}{|\boldsymbol{r}|}+\frac{m_\mathrm{M}}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_\mathrm{M}|}\right)$ be the gravitational potential. The gravitational force reads
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}) = -\gamma m_\mathrm{R}\left(\frac{m_\mathrm{E}}{|\boldsymbol{r}|^3}\boldsymbol{r}+\frac{m_\mathrm{M}}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_\mathrm{M}|^3}(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_\mathrm{M})\right).
\end{equation}
The angular momentum with respect to the origin is however not conserved as
\begin{equation}
\dot{\boldsymbol{L}} = \boldsymbol{r}\times\boldsymbol{F} = \frac{\gamma m_\mathrm{R} m_\mathrm{M}}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_\mathrm{M}|^3}\,\boldsymbol{r}\times\boldsymbol{r}_\mathrm{M}.
\end{equation}
I also thought about choosing another coordinate system (e.g. center of mass) but this did not work. Any ideas how to show this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Conservation laws often come from symmetries of the Hamiltonian. In this case, in order to conserve angular momentum you would need a rotationally symmetric Hamiltonian. But a system of two point masses is not rotationally symmetric and therefore, as you have discovered, the angular momentum of the rocket is not conserved.

If the initial position and velocity of the rocket, the Moon and the Earth lie on the same plane, you can expect that the motion will be restricted to such plane. Otherwise, the trajectory will be tridimensional.

---

The intuitive proof of this statement is that the force always lies in the plane formed by $\vec{r}_M$ and $\vec{r}(t)$, therefore the rocket won't feel any force orthogonal to the plane. If the velocity lies on this plane too, the rocket won't leave the plane and the orbit is planar.

A somewhat more rigorous proof:

An orbit is said planar if it is fully contained in a plane.  This statement can be written as
$$\exists \vec{w} : (\vec{r}(t)-\vec{r}_0)\cdot\vec{w} = 0 \tag 1$$
where $\vec{r}_0$ is the initial position (at $t=0$) and $\vec{w}$ is the vector normal to the plane of the orbit. Differentiating the equation one obtains:
$$\dot{\vec{r}}(t) \cdot \vec{w} = 0  \tag 2$$
$$\ddot{\vec{r}}(t) \cdot \vec{w} = 0 \tag 3$$

This means that both velocity and acceleration must lie on the same plane for the whole motion.

Let's consider the plane formed by the vectors $\vec{F}(\vec{r}_0)$ and $\vec{r}_M$, and let $\vec{w} = \vec{F}(\vec{r}_0) \times \vec{r}_M$. It is easy to see that for every point $\vec{r}$ on the plane, equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ hold.

If we want a planar orbit, it is necessary at this point to choose the initial velocity such that $\vec{v}_0 \cdot \vec{w} = 0$, and you can see that after a small time
$$\vec{v}(\delta t) \cdot \vec{w} = (\vec{v}_0 + \dot{\vec{v}}\delta t) \cdot \vec{w} = \vec{v}_0 \cdot \vec{w} + (\vec{F}(\vec{r}_0) \cdot \vec{w}) \delta t/m = 0$$

In other words, as long as the rocket is on the plane, its velocity will keep lying on it.

Comment: Thank you. I exactly want to describe what you write in the second paragraph, but I did not manage to show this mathematically. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I know, the last part of the proof I added is not rigorous. But I wasn't able to find a better way to say it

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum is conserved if the force points always to the system COM, that means: it is radial, so that $\mathbf r \times \mathbf F = 0$.

It is not the case for the Earth-Moon system. For example: any object nearby the Moon will not fall to the system COM, or an astronaut could not walk in the Moon surface.

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum of the system; earth, moon, and rocket, can be conserved. The the angular momentum of the rocket cannot.  The rocket will be subject to two forces. At least one of these will produce a torque about any chosen reference point.